# Unable to import ssleay32.dll !Programme will exit

Tags: windows-ce

I am using Virtual cepc to execute the wince 2013 application.My application requires the ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll so i copied these two files to my .exe application folder in virtual cepc.But still while running it tells that Unable to import library SSLEAY32.dll ! Program will exit..I changed C/C++ code generation run time option to MT but still i get no solution. Please tell me solution to this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you builing those DLLs yourself? Or you just have binaries? If you have binaries, are those binaries for the right CE architecture (x86) and version (Windows Embedded Compact 2013 is not backward compatible with CE 7)?
If you have the code, check that it does not depend on other external components, and if it has dependencies on the OS, it may be that the OS you are currently using has a different set of components compared to the one you used to generate the SDK that you are using to build your DLL.
Windows CE is very componentizable and some functions may be missing on a specific device and available on others, that's why you can generate a device-specific SDK.
You may also use dependency walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to open your DLL file and check if it has dependencies on other DLLs or what OS functions it uses (most of them are exported by coredll.dll).

Comment: Hi,Thanks Valter . As you know i am targeting  to stand alone CEPC  for testing which requires a Wince 2013 run time OS image to be created and boot.Currently i am creating the run time OS image myself and to enable features i am adding the SYSGEN variables.Is it that for openSSL (ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll) to be use i need the corresponding SYSGEN variable to be added while creating the OS run time image??

Comment: So you built those DLL using the SDK you generated from the OSDesign used to create the image?

Comment: Do i need to add SYSGEN variable for open ssl to be configured while creating OS runtime image?If yes can you please tell me?

Comment: Win32 desktop DLLs are not binary compatible with ce. If you have the code you may (may) be able to build it for ce, otherwise there is no way to run those DLLs on a Windows CE device.